# How to trigger an event when a web notification is displayed in React.js

Tags: reactjs, onesignal, web-push

I want to update the UI when a new web push notification is received from OneSignal. I am using the npm package of OneSignal, I tried to create an event listener but  I'm not sure what's wrong here. The App is able to get notifications and show them.

```
import OneSignal from "react-onesignal";
export async function runOneSignalOnLogin(data) {
    await OneSignal.init({
      appId: process.env.REACT_APP_ONE_SIGNAL_ID,
      allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true,
    });
    OneSignal.showSlidedownPrompt();
    OneSignal.setExternalUserId(`${data?.user?.organization_id}`);
    OneSignal.on("notificationDisplay", function (isSubscribed) {
    console.log("The user's subscription state is now:", isSubscribed);
  });
  }
export function runOneSignalOnLogout() {
  OneSignal.removeExternalUserId();
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @Konrad, Not a signal event listener works for me. how can I listen to OneSignal Event with ReactJS (and do something else with that data) after I received the notification?
 I want to grab data (id, heading, content, data, e.t.c) from the notification.